# Drag number of 1 from the database

Tags: sql

it is such that I should just pull a number from sql in my updater, and that is how I have 20 numbers right now, but I click on my button so it goes down and just say -1.

I would like that it went down and said 19 instead of 20 when I clicked my button.

```
UPDATE danshold SET Maxantal = -1 WHERE Id = @tilmeldButton
```

Comment: To modify a column in place, use an expression like `SET Maxantal = Maxantal - 1`  Using `SET Maxantal = -1` is literally assigning `-1` to the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to actually decrement the column value, not just set it to the value of -1:

```
UPDATE 
  danshold 
SET 
  Maxantal = Maxantal - 1 
WHERE 
  Id = @tilmeldButton
```